# AssertionError: ../final_dataset\trainA is not a valid directory

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am getting error even after placing the corresponding folder trainA in train_dataset folder

Options

```
D_P_times2: False
IN_vgg: False
batchSize: 32
beta1: 0.5
checkpoints_dir: ./checkpoints
config: configs/unit_gta2city_folder.yaml
continue_train: False
dataroot: ../final_dataset
dataset_mode: unaligned
display_freq: 30
display_id: 1
display_port: 8097
display_single_pane_ncols: 0
display_winsize: 256
fcn: 0
fineSize: 320
gpu_ids: [0, 1, 2]
high_times: 400
hybrid_loss: True
identity: 0.0
input_linear: False
input_nc: 3
instance_norm: 0.0
isTrain: True
l1: 10.0
lambda_A: 10.0
lambda_B: 10.0
latent_norm: False
latent_threshold: False
lighten: False
linear: False
linear_add: False
loadSize: 286
low_times: 200
lr: 0.0001
max_dataset_size: inf
model: single
multiply: False
nThreads: 4
n_layers_D: 5
n_layers_patchD: 4
name: enlightening
ndf: 64
new_lr: False
ngf: 64
niter: 100
niter_decay: 100
no_dropout: True
no_flip: False
no_html: False
no_lsgan: False
no_vgg_instance: False
noise: 0
norm: instance
norm_attention: False
output_nc: 3
patchD: True
patchD_3: 5
patchSize: 32
patch_vgg: True
phase: train
pool_size: 50
print_freq: 100
resize_or_crop: crop
save_epoch_freq: 5
save_latest_freq: 5000
self_attention: True
serial_batches: False
skip: 1.0
syn_norm: False
tanh: False
times_residual: True
use_avgpool: 0
use_mse: False
use_norm: 1.0
use_ragan: True
use_wgan: 0.0
vary: 1
vgg: 1.0
vgg_choose: relu5_1
vgg_maxpooling: False
vgg_mean: False
which_direction: AtoB
which_epoch: latest
which_model_netD: no_norm_4
which_model_netG: sid_unet_resize
```

Output

```
CustomDatasetDataLoader
dataset [UnalignedDataset] was created
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\THESIS\Code\EnlightenGAN-master\train.py", line 14, in <module>
    data_loader = CreateDataLoader(opt)
  File "D:\THESIS\Code\EnlightenGAN-master\data\data_loader.py", line 6, in CreateDataLoader
    data_loader.initialize(opt)
  File "D:\THESIS\Code\EnlightenGAN-master\data\custom_dataset_data_loader.py", line 39, in initialize
    self.dataset = CreateDataset(opt)
  File "D:\THESIS\Code\EnlightenGAN-master\data\custom_dataset_data_loader.py", line 29, in CreateDataset
    dataset.initialize(opt)
  File "D:\THESIS\Code\EnlightenGAN-master\data\unaligned_dataset.py", line 65, in initialize
    self.A_imgs, self.A_paths = store_dataset(self.dir_A)
  File "D:\THESIS\Code\EnlightenGAN-master\data\image_folder.py", line 39, in store_dataset
    assert os.path.isdir(dir), '%s is not a valid directory' % dir
AssertionError: ../final_dataset\trainA is not a valid directory
```

I have changed the backslash() with forward slash(/) in the following code and tried, still the error occured

```
assert os.path.isdir(dir.replace('\\','/')), '%s is not a valid directory' % dir
```

Comment: It looks like the `\t` in `"../final_dataset\trainA"` is a single tab character. `dir.replace('\\','/')` wouldn't do any good because this is a python string literal - `\t` was converted to a tab by the compiler before any code is run. Is this string in your source somewhere? Where does it come from?